# Risk scoring in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a metric to detect fraud, say calls, transfer rate, aux time, and so on.

I have grouped them into bins based on quartiles and now I have to give ratings from 1 to 5 based on bins. For example: calls > 150 assign ranking as 1, calls <=150 and >=300 as 2 and so on. Likewise for all the metrics.

I tried the following:

```
np.where(x.Calls<=125.8,1,
np.where(x.Calls>=153.2 & x.Calls<=190.0,2,np.where(x.Calls>=190.0 & x.Calls<=235.0,3,np.where(x.Calls>=235.0 & x.Calls<=304.4,4,np.where(x.Calls>=304.4,5,0))))
```

Error:

> `File "<ipython-input-32-41fe2292e308>", line 2`
>   `np.where(x.Calls>=153.2 & x.Calls<=190.0,2,np.where(x.Calls>=190.0 &`
>   `x.Calls<=235.0,3,np.where(x.Calls>=235.0 &`
>   `x.Calls<=304.4,4,np.where(x.Calls>=304.4,5,0))))`
>
> `^ SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`

I want the code to take the range of values from the quartiles got and give ratings to it on its own.

Comment: You have 5 opening parentheses but only 4 closing parentheses. Oh, and you may want to change those ampersands (&) to the word `and`.

Answer (score 0):

Your specific error indicates that you have left some parentheses open.

But you're getting this error because the nested `np.where` approach is really hard to implement (and therefore debug and maintain). So it's worth thinking about other ways.

The rules you want to implement aren't totally clear to me, but I think [`np.digitize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) might help you make progress. It 'quantizes' your data: you give it an array-like of bins, and it returns the bin each value of an array appears in. It works like this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([55, 99, 65, 121, 189, 205, 211, 304, 999])
>>> bins = [100, 200, 300]
>>> np.digitize(a, bins=bins)
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3])
```